# Log4Net: Custom appender from referenced DLL is ignored

Tags: c#, log4net

I created a very simple appender from subclassing `AppenderSkeleton`. I put this into an extra library and referenced it. The relevant part of my `app.config` in the program where I use it is:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="${LOCALAPPDATA}\MyProgram\MyLog.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
      </layout>
      <threshold value="Debug" />
    </appender>
    <appender name="MySimpleAppender" type="Some.Namespace.SimpleAppender" >
      <threshold value="Info" />
    </appender>
    <root>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="MySimpleAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

The configurator is setup in `Program.cs` like this:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

When I now log something, e.g.:

```
LOG.Info("foo");
```

the message gets written to the file (using the `FileAppender`), but my `SimpleAppender` is ignored. When I explicitly create a nullary constructor and set a breakpoint to it, I see that it is not even instantiated. When I copy the class file directly into the project where my program resides in, it works.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you added a reference to your assembly? I bet if you enable log4net's own diagnostics, you'll see that your assembly can't be found

Comment: You were right, my assembly is not found. It says `Could not load type [Some.Namespace.SimpleAppender]. Tried assembly [log4net, Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=deadbabed00faffe] and all loaded assemblies`. However, the assembly IS referenced. How do I achieve that the referenced assembly is loaded before?

Comment: It doesn't have to be loaded *before* log4net. The problem is that the assembly isn't found by .NET itself. Your assembly must be discoverable just like any other assembly - it should be in the same folder, in the GAC, or your config should contain a `dependentAssembly`element that points to it.  *How* did you add the reference? Is the assembly deployed to the same folder as the application? Did you forget perhaps to set  the `Copy Local` property of the reference to True?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the assembly name to the type tag. Right now it is looking in the Log4Net assembly.

It takes the format

```
type="Namespace,AssemblyName"
```

So much like

```
 <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
```

You need

```
<appender name="MySimpleAppender" type="Some.Namespace.SimpleAppender,MyAssembly" >
```